# I can't retrieve the value in a table cell printed from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
function printTable($name, $credit){
    print"
        <tr onMouseOver='color(this)' onMouseOut='trans(this)' id='row'>
            <td>$name</td>
            <td>$credit</td>
        </tr>
    ";
}
```

What I have here is a function within my php file that prints $name and $credit.

Initially, the php does a search in my database and calls this function by sending the two parameters.

So, when the page is first loaded, the table is not shown; it's shown only when I do a search.

Now, when I click on the row, I want the page to pop up an alert messege with the value in the cell.

Below is jquery I wrote to perform that action.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#row").click(function(){
            var value=$(this).find("td:first").html();
            alert(value);
        });
    });
    function color(row){
        row.style.backgroundColor = "#F3F781";
    }
    function trans(row){
        row.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
    }
</script>
```

However, the jquery is not working; it pops up nothing when I click it.

The only thing that works right now is the highlighting function when I put my mouse over it.

Why is this not working? and how do I solve this?

edit:

solved by answer in the comments

Comment: Provide the ouput table in html from your snippet in PHP

Comment: seems to [work just fine for me](http://jsbin.com/movacoziwe/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: If table is added later you need to use event delegation: `$(document).on('click', '#row', function() {`

Comment: @jcubic Thank you! Your method worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax to get content from php and put it in the html code, so you will be able to use jquery to manipulate the html

Answer (score 0):

Change the click event selector from id to class.. You cant achieve all the respective rows click using an id as a selector..

Html:

```
    <tr onMouseOver='color(this)' onMouseOut='trans(this)' class='row'>
        <td>$name</td>
        <td>$credit</td>
    </tr>
```

Jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".row").click(function(){
        var value=$(this).find("td:first").html();
        alert(value);
    });
    });
```